# How to add a blank line in PowerShell array?

Tags: powershell

I'm a novice in PowerShell and just started to learn this stuff. I have been following this link

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-powershell-sample-collect-vm-details

to get a list of all VM's. It's working fine. I want to insert a 'line break' or a blank line whenever the resource group name changes.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: A new line can be produced by `n.

Comment: Would you mind showing me this code?  Looking at the sample script, looks like the array is $report.  the result produces about ten columns in the output.  How would I populate the $report with ten blanks?  I'm a DBA and I don't do PS but I have need to work with that script now.  Thanks!

Comment: @sydney - Sounds more like a Stack Overflow question.  Be sure you provide a minimal example code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @sydney - adding blanks to your CSV is a poor solution since that corrupts your data. [*grin*] instead, keep the data clean and fiddle with the _report_. it's fairly easy to iterate thru the collection and add a literal blank line when one column changes. better, tho, would be to use `Group-Object` and then list out the groups in the order you want with whatever logical visual break you want. also, for pure display ... the `Format-Table` cmdlet has a `-GroupBy` parameter ... [*grin*]

Comment: Lee_Dailey, thanks.  I will research your proposed solution and see how far I can get.  The reason why I want a 'break' or 'blank' line when the Resource Group (RG) changes is I can quickly glance at the output and tell which group of VM's belong to which RG.